# What is resource id #170?

Tags: php, database, joomla

what i am trying to achieve here is that i want to retrieve data from Joomla's database.. Using the code, below, i am able to connect to Joomla's database successfully.. But the problem is, $query1 displayed this output, "resource id #170".. We tried connecting to different tables to see if we are able to get different output, but same output appear.. So i am wondering, what does that message means? Is it somethings wrong with the code, or database or etc..

```
<?php 
session_start();
ob_start();
?>

<html>
<head>
<body>

<?php
include 'config.php';

//This is an example opendb.php
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');
mysql_select_db($dbname);
echo $dbname;
echo ('connected successfully!!!');

?>

<?php 

$query1 = "select speciesName from jos_mainDBspecies where species_id ='1'"; 
$result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
$row1  = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);
extract($row1);
echo $result1;


?>
```

Many thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: A resource is the name for a database connection, database query object, opened file, etc.

Comment: Are you sure your output doesn't originate in that line: `echo $dbname;` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$result1` is a MySQL result resource. It is supposed to be like this. Your actual result is in `$row1` in your code.

Comment: we changed this line, "echo $row1;" and we got this output, "Array". Sorry, may i know what is this problem?

Comment: You are getting `Array`, because your result always holds an entire row, even if you are selecting a single column. Try `print_r($row1)`; or seeing how you have already `extract()`-ed your result, you could just access it as `$speciesName`.